# Error embedded nul in string: when trying to open rds files in Windows system (code works fine in a Mac)

Tags: r, windows, rds

I have multiple rds files that I would like to merge. I am using the following code but i get the error :

```
Error in readRDS(x) : 
  embedded nul in string: '`$\t`$!`$<`%\0`$8`$>, `$-`$>`$0`$$'
```

Code:

```
require(data.table)
files = list.files(pattern = '^2020_01_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}\\.rds$')
dat_list = lapply(files, function (x) data.table(readRDS(x)))
dat = rbindlist(dat_list, fill = TRUE)
```

I am using a Windows system. When I run the same code with the same files in a Mac system, it works.

Comment: This question is all about `readRDS`, nothing to do with `data.table` or combining data, right? Does it behave any differently without any of the other code here?

Comment: Yes, this is about readRDS. Sorry about not being clear. I get the same error even when I try to open a single file using readRDS("filename.rds")

Comment: It's likely going to be difficult to reproduce. I can safely transfer a rather bland rds file from windows to linux and back with no problem, so it's not the protocol (though byte 9 was different when the contents were the same, seen with `od -x` cli tool). I suggest you remove all code outside of `readRDS` (since it is not affecting things); when you fix `readRDS`, I assume the rest of the code will fall into place. It might be useful if you can reproduce this with sample data (or structures or whatever you have in there).

Comment: How are you transferring files between systems? Some protocols adjust for different line endings between operating systems. But because rds files are binary, there should be no transformation. If the files are being moved as text, corruption can happen.

Comment: I am transferring files using scp.